# Android database Application context fails

Tags: android, database, lifecycle

This article shows the different database approaches nicely:

[database approaches](http://www.ragtag.info/2011/feb/1/database-pitfalls/)

I use approach 2: An Application object which holds the single LocalDatabaseAdapter I made. This holds a DatabaseOpenHelper etc.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


private static LocalDbAdapter lDb;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
[..]
}
public static LocalDbAdapter getLDb(){
    if(lDb==null){
        lDb = new LocalDbAdapter(context);
    }
    if(lDb.isOpen()){
        return lDb;
    }else{
        return lDb.open();
    }
}
@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
    lDb.close();
}
```

Now when I start the camera app and then return to my main activity, I get the database never closed error. As it points out, this db was created in the Application context, so why is it a problem that I dont close it in my Activity, I thought that was the idea. An important adavantage of having only one database object is that all methods of LocalDbAdapter that do any writing use the protected(this) statement around the insert or update.

In OnActivityResult, after the camera has taken a picture, I acquire the database like

```
LocalDbAdapter ldb = MyApplication.getLDb();
```

This has me seriously bummed out. If I close it in onPause of my MainActivity, I'm afraid that a background service using the same object gets in trouble, and Im even keeping the object local to the onActivityResult...

Comment: If you want to keep one database object then go for singleton design patteren.Dont do it in application class.Since Application class is made for some other purpose not the purpose for which you are using

Comment: @Nino check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562201/android-thinks-im-not-closing-my-database-why

Comment: But if I make a singleton outside application class, wont it be destroyed when any activity finishes?